# Jquery select odd objects in array

Tags: arrays, visibility

I am trying to apply a css style to only the odd objects of an array.
It didn't work. My code so far is,

```
var products = [
    { title: 'Botín', price: 800.44, category: 'Botines', image: 'images/005030000D65804_1.jpg', brand: 'nike' },
    { title: 'Ojotas', price: 300.99, category: 'Ojotas', image: 'images/004632000F88356_1.jpg', brand: 'adidas' },
    { title: 'Zapatillas', price: 1120.00, category: 'Calzado', image: 'images/077632604336703_1.jpg', brand: 'puma' },
    { title: 'Short', price: 320.44, category: 'Vestimenta', image: 'images/077652619598012_1.jpg', brand: 'nike' },
    { title: 'Jabulani South Africa 2010', price: 700.52, category: 'Pelotas', image: 'images/adidas-jabulani-photo.jpg', brand: 'nike' },
    { title: 'Zapatillas', price: 1120.00, category: 'Calzado', image: 'images/077632604336703_1.jpg', brand: 'puma' },
    { title: 'Short', price: 320.44, category: 'Vestimenta', image: 'images/077652619598012_1.jpg', brand: 'nike' },
    { title: 'Jabulani South Africa 2010', price: 700.52, category: 'Pelotas', image: 'images/adidas-jabulani-photo.jpg', brand: 'nike' }
    ];

    $(products).each(function(i, obj) {
        $('#espacio-articulos').append('<article class="articulo"><img class="image" src="'+obj.image+'"/><div class="oferta">OFERTA</div><span class="title">'+obj.title+'</span><span class="price">$ '+obj.price+'</span><span class="brand '+obj.brand+'"></span><span class="category">'+obj.category+'</span>');
        e = i+3;
        if (e % 2) {
            $('.oferta').css('visibility','visible');
        }
    });
```

I have to apply .oferta visibility to items that are odd. Only these elements (which are odd). Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply css rule to elements which have odd position only change your code as shown below:

```
...
$(products).each(function(i, obj) {
    $('#espacio-articulos').append('<article class="articulo"><img class="image" src="'+obj.image+'"/><div class="oferta">OFERTA</div><span class="title">'+obj.title+'</span><span class="price">$ '+obj.price+'</span><span class="brand '+obj.brand+'"></span><span class="category">'+obj.category+'</span>');
    if (i % 2 > 0) {
        $('#espacio-articulos article:last .oferta').css('visibility','visible');
    }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks! I hope to be helpful